# Can I use @Bean from AndroidAnnotation within Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-annotations

Can I use `@Bean` from `AndroidAnnotation` within `Kotlin`?

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_test)
open class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   @Bean
   var test:TestBean //<-- IDE shows "property must be initialized or abstract"
```

This is my `Bean` declaration

```
@EBean
class TestBean {

  fun printShit(){
    Log.e("ASDF","ASDF")
  }
}
```

Is this somehow possible? Or do I have to use kotlins `object` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark it [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) to avoid having to initialize it.

```
@Bean
lateinit var test: TestBean
```

By doing so, you're telling the compiler that you're sure it will be initialized before the first time you use it. If it doesn't get initialized and you try to use it, this will throw an exception.